# Any recommendations for deep data structures with Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've run into a headache with Backbone.  I have a collection of specified records, which have subrecords, for example: surgeons have scheduled procedures, procedures have equipment, some equipment has consumable needs (gasses, liquids, etc).  If I have a Backbone collection *surgeons*, then each surgeon has a model-- but his procedures and equipment and consumables will all be plain ol' Javascript arrays and objects after being unpacked from JSON.

I suppose I could, in the SurgeonsCollection, use the parse() to make new ProcedureCollections, and in turn make new EquipmentCollections, but after a while this is turning into a hairball.  To make it sensible server-side there's a single point of contact that takes one surgeon and his stuff as a POST-- so propagating the 'set' on a ConsumableModel automagically to trigger a 'save' down the hierarchy also makes the whole hierarchical approach fuzzy.

Has anyone else encountered a problem like this?  How did you solve it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be helpful in you case: https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational

You specify the relations 1:1, 1:n, n:n and it will parse the JSON accordingly. It also create a global store to keep track of all records.

Comment: [Ligament.js](https://github.com/dbrady/ligament.js) is another possible solution.

Comment: Backbone-relational is almost entirely the answer to my dreams.  I was headed down that road early on, but this is better thought-out and more elegant.

Answer (score 4):

So, one way I solved this problem is by doing the following:

1. Have all models inherit from a custom BaseModel and put the following function in BaseModel:

   ```
       convertToModel: function(dataType, modelType) {
           if (this.get(dataType)) {
               var map = { };
               map[dataType] = new modelType(this.get(dataType));
               this.set(map);
           }
       }
   ```
2. Override Backbone.sync and at first let the Model serialize as it normally would:

   model.set(response, { silent: true });
3. Then check to see if the model has an onUpdate function:

   ```
               if (model.onUpdate) {
                   model.onUpdate();
               }
   ```
4. Then, whenever you have a model that you want to generate submodels and subcollections, implement onUpdate in the model with something like this:

   ```
           onUpdate: function() {
               this.convertToModel('nameOfAttribute1', SomeCustomModel1);
               this.convertToModel('nameOfAttribute2', SomeCustomModel2);
           }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I would separate out the different surgeons, procedures, equipment, etc. as different resources in your web service.  If you only need to update the equipment for a particular procedure, you can update that one procedure.

Also, if you didn't always need all the information, I would also lazy-load data as needed, but send down fully-populated objects where needed to increase performance.

Comment: I just want to comment that your suggestion, while laudable, defeats the purpose of a RESTful interface, in which the coarse document (in this case, Procedure) is passed back-and-forth between the server and the client.